# For $f_n$ a mollification of $f$, do we have $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere implies $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||f_n||_{L^2} = ||f||_{L^2}$?

Tags: lp-spaces, convolution, pointwise-convergence, almost-everywhere

$J_{\delta}$ is a standard mollifier. $f'\in L^2[\delta', 1-\delta']$ is the weak derivative of some $f\in L^2[\delta', 1-\delta']$, with $\delta < \delta'$.

Then we know $(J_{\delta}*f)'=J_{\delta}*(f')$.

We know $(J_{\delta}*f)' \to f'$ almost everywhere on $[\delta', 1-\delta']$.

I also know that $(J_{\delta}*f)' \rightharpoonup f'$.

I want to use [Radon Riesz property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Riesz_property) to show that $(J_{\delta}*f)' \to f'$ strongly.

**So I'm left with showing** $\lim_{\delta \to 0} ||(J_{\delta}*f)'||_{L^2} = ||f'||_{L^2}$.

I think this must follow from the pointwise convergence, since if it would follow from the weak convergence, then this additional condition in Radon Riesz property wouldn't be necessary.

We want
$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0} \int ((J_{\delta}*f)'(x))^2\;dx = \int (f'(x))^2 dx
$$

I don't know where to start. I have also noticed that $||(J_\delta * f)'||_{L^2}=||J_\delta * (f')||_{L^2} \leq ||J_\delta||_{L^1} * ||f'||_{L^2} = ||f'||_{L^2}$ by Young's convolution inequality, so

$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0} \int ((J_{\delta}*f)'(x))^2\;dx \leq \int (f'(x))^2 dx,
$$

but I don't know if that brings us any closer to getting that $\leq$ to an $=$.

Comment: the result in the title is true without the assumption of $f_n\to f$ a.e. You can show what you want directly, i believe the proof in the appendix of e.g. Evans "Partial Differential Equations" is quite complete

Comment: @CalvinKhor I cannot find it there. I did think of something else, which I want to post as an answer: If I can show that $((J_{\delta}*f)')^2$ is uniformly bounded on $[2\delta', 1-2\delta']$, I can use the dominated convergence theorem to show $\int ((J_{\delta} * f)')^2 \;dx \to \int (f')^2\;dx$ because we know that $((J_{\delta} * f)')^2 \to (f')^2$ pointwise. I do however have some boundary issues in my proof.